# Is this the correct connection between a metric tensor and the surface patches that describe a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand some basics about differential geometry. What I've mostly read so far is Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry, but now I'm looking at other sources and I'm having some trouble connecting the dots.

Pressley mostly focuses on surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ which can be described by (atlases of) surface patches $\sigma(u, v): \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. This all makes sense to me, but he doesn't (explicitly) talk about metrics.

(I know this all generally applies to higher dimensions, but it'd be helpful to keep it simple with $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ here.)

I think I get the point of the metric tensor $g$: to define a position-dependent inner product for the surface, i.e., how to take the dot product of two tangent vectors at any point on the surface.

My question is about how I should view the connection between the metric tensor and the surface patch (let's just assume that one covers the whole surface for now), and what's "fundamental" to the surface itself.

For example, it seems like in Pressley's style, given the paraboloid surface $x^2 + y^2 - z = 0$, we could use the surface patch $\sigma(u, v) = (u, v, u^2 + v^2)$, and then any tangent vector can be expressed as $v = \alpha \sigma_u + \beta \sigma_v$, and we can just take the inner product of two tangent vectors at any position, by taking the dot product of $\mathbb R^3$ of them (is this correct?). I've seen this described (in O'Neill's book of the same name) as the "induced metric"; is that right?

Is the equivalent idea, if we instead just had the metric tensor, essentially pretending we have a flat surface in $\mathbb R^2$, and then using the metric tensor to find the inner product at a given $(u, v)$?